# Repeat a line command?

Tags: vim, viemu

I'm new to the more advanced aspects of vi/vim/viemu

I commonly need to select a bit of text and indent/undent, among other things. Right now I have two ways to do this:

- select the text and use `<<`
- use a multi-line command such as `:198,205<<`

Now, sometimes I need to do this multiple times. When using the dot command though(`.`) it will never repeat my last command unless I was previously in insert mode. Instead, it will just delete the current line.

Is there a quick and easy way of doing this?

Comment: What does this have to do with Visual Studio?

Comment: @SLaks ViEmu, presumably.  There can always be differences between vim and the ViEmu implementation thereof.

Comment: @SLacks, yes what Andrew said. I figured the viemu and visual-studio tag went hand-in-hand

Comment: I had never heard of ViEmu until now. I was kinda wondering the same thing... :-)

Comment: It's a pretty great little extension. The bad part is they hook you by giving you a 30 day free trial. At the end of the trial, I suppose you get use to vi and can't live without it. But it's fairly cheap at $99 for a single developer(across unlimited machines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `V` to visually select the lines and then press the keys `5` then `>` to indent the lines 5 tabs to the right (or just `<` to indent once to the left).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to auto-indent the entire file use `gg=G`. `gg` move to the beginning of the file, `=` auto-indent function, `G` to the end of the file. This will indent code based on block nesting levels.

For what it's worth, `>G` will indent all the lines one tab to the right from the cursor position to the end of file.

You can also auto-indent text marked with the `m` bookmark function, i.e. position cursor at start, `ma`, position the cursor at end, `='a`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question quite directly, but awesome tip!